# ffmpeg filter complex error ( burning subtitles used overlay filter)

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, overlay, subtitle

I try to burn dvb subtitles, based image, on video used ffmpeg overlay filter. but I failed because wrong using filter complex.

It's my command line.

```
./ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -hwaccel_device 0 \
-i input.ts \
-filter_complex "[v:0][s:3]overlay[overlay];[overlay]hwupload_cuda[base];[base]scale_npp=1920:1080[v1];[base]scale_npp=1920:1080[v2];[base]scale_npp=1280:720[v3];[base]scale_npp=720:480[v4];[base]scale_npp=480:360[v5]" \
-map "[v1]" -map 0:a -c:v hevc_nvenc -b:v 6000000 -maxrate 7000000 -bufsize 12000000 -g 15 -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -f mpegts test_1.ts \
-map "[v2]" -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -an -b:v 4000000 -maxrate 5000000 -bufsize 8000000 -g 15 -f mpegts test_2.ts \
-map "[v3]" -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -an -b:v 2500000 -maxrate 3500000 -bufsize 5000000 -g 15 -f mpegts test_3.ts \
-map "[v4]" -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -an -b:v 1500000 -maxrate 2500000 -bufsize 3000000 -g 15 -f mpegts test_4.ts \
-map "[v5]" -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -an -b:v 800000 -maxrate 1800000 -bufsize 2000000 -g 15 -f mpegts test_5.ts
```

but I failed. It is error messages.

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
Duration: N/A, start: 22881.964411, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100](eng): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x101](ind): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x102](zho): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x103](kho): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x104]: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(top first, left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:5[0x105](CHI): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:6[0x106](CHS): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:7[0x107](IND): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:8[0x108](THA): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:9[0x109](MAN): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:10[0x10a](MON): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:11[0x10b](BUR): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:12[0x10c](ENG): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    [mpegts @ 0x47cbd00] Invalid stream specifier: base.
    Last message repeated 17 times
    Stream specifier 'base' in filtergraph description [v:0][s:3]overlay[overlay];[overlay]hwupload_cuda[base];[base]scale_npp=1920:1080[v1];[base]scale_npp=1920:1080[v2];[base]scale_npp=1280:720[v3];[base]scale_npp=720:480[v4];[base]scale_npp=480:360[v5] matches no streams.
```

My plan is this.
[image]

How to do burn subtitle on video using filter complex, ffmpeg from this structure?

Comment: "Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production"

Answer (score 1):

You can not re-use outputs from a filterchain. You can use the [split / asplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split) filters to make copies of a filter output to be used multiple times.

Simplified example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[0][1]overlay,split=outputs=3[s1][s2][s3];[s1]scale=-2:1080[1080];[s2]scale=-2:720[720];[s3]scale=-2:360[360]" \
-map "[1080]" -map 0:a 1080.ts \
-map "[720]"  -map 0:a 720.ts \
-map "[360]"  -map 0:a 360.ts
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's my command line followed your comment.

Comment: It makes error message Probably because of my mistake. but I didn't solve it.

Comment: @jgkim0518 This answer is only to address the original question regarding `Stream specifier 'base' in filtergraph description ... matches no streams.` Now you are encountering a completely new and different error: `Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented`. You should ask a new question about that. Stack Overflow works best if you ask 1 question per post instead of asking multiple follow up questions. You will get more and faster answers that way. And always include the complete log.